PDF2HTMLEX putting text in images
I was using pdf2htmlex to parse a question paper when I realized that it was saving text as part of the image rather than just graphics in the image
Here's an example
Example
Something to note is that pdf2htmlex is able to read the text off of the PDF - its not as if the text is unrecognizable. Upon inspecting the pdf file further, the divs do contain text form the pdf, but they are transparent.
I tried checking if maybe different font families is the problem using fitz. Maybe it still is, but I ran this code :
import fitz

def extract_fonts_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    font_families = set()
    
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    for page_num in range(len(doc)):
        page = doc.load_page(page_num)

        for text_instance in page.get_text("dict")["blocks"]:
            for line in text_instance["lines"]:
                for span in line["spans"]:
                    font_family = span["font"]
                    if font_family:
                        font_families.add(font_family)

    doc.close()
    return font_families

def compare_fonts(pdf_path1, pdf_path2):
    fonts1 = extract_fonts_from_pdf(pdf_path1)
    fonts2 = extract_fonts_from_pdf(pdf_path2)

    print("Fonts in PDF 1:")
    print(fonts1)
    print("\nFonts in PDF 2:")
    print(fonts2)

# Example usage
pdf_path1 = "eq8.pdf"
pdf_path2 = "example.pdf"
compare_fonts(pdf_path1, pdf_path2)


Where example.pdf is a pdf that parses correctly (the image only contains graphics, no text) and eq8.pdf is one where text is included in the image.
This is the output :
Fonts in PDF 1:
{'Arial', 'Calibri', 'TimesNRGreekMT', 'Arial,Bold', 'Helvetica-Bold', 'Arial,Italic', 'Helvetica', 'Symbol', 'Cambria,Bold', 'Helvetica-Oblique'}

Fonts in PDF 2:
{'Arial', 'Calibri', 'Arial,Bold', 'Helvetica-Bold', 'Arial,Italic', 'Helvetica', 'Cambria,Bold', 'Helvetica-Oblique'}

Could someone please inform me whether or not there's some sort of option to disable this behavior (text in the image files) so I only get graphics in the image files? It's messing my image parsing algorithm up...

I was asking if there was a way to disable the text overlay on the images. I use pdf2htmlex as I find it to be much better at extracting text than other software such as PyPDF2 (which, at least in my case, created multiple whitespace errors). Additionally, preserving the images and formatting of the text is also important for my task. But the specific styling of the text (font families, etc) isn't really necessary. I was asking if there was a way to stop pdf2htmlex from focusing on styling the text.

Figured out the answer. It was due to some bad quality PDFs where, instead of text on the PDF, there was simply an image of the text pasted on the PDF. This was apparent on turning --correct-text-visibility 0. Thanks everyone.
